# How to use MySQL's LIKE in Prisma ORM on non string fields?

Tags: mysql, orm, prisma

Having some experience in writing raw SQL queries for some time, I want to use Prisma in Node.js to ask MySQL for something like that:

`SELECT ..... WHERE dateField LIKE '2020-05%'`

or

`SELECT ..... WHERE numberField LIKE '%99'`

I know, that the database will return what I want.

I just can't make Prisma to do that. Is it possible?

For string/varchar fields i use `contains` keyword in `where` object and it works fine.

```
const orders = await prisma.order.findMany({
  where: {
    textField: {
        contains: 'test'
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any workaround to get such functionality for date/number type fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to run raw SQL in Prisma as a workaround:

```
const orders = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM Order WHERE dataField LIKE '%-05-%'`;
```

It can even be type casted:

```
import { Order } from '@prisma/client'
const orders = await prisma.$queryRaw<Order[]>`SELECT * FROM Order WHERE dataField LIKE '%-05-%'`;
```

Not pretty, but works as intended.