# How to use LIKE in Prisma ORM on number fields?

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma

Having some experience in writing raw SQL queries, I want to use Prisma in Node.js to ask Postgresql for something like that:

```query
SELECT ..... WHERE dateField LIKE '2020-05%'
```

or

```query
SELECT ..... WHERE numberField LIKE '%99'
```

I know, that the database will return what I want.

I just can't make Prisma do that. Is it possible?

For string/varchar fields I use contains the keyword in where object and it works fine.

```js
const orders = await prisma.product.findMany({
  where: {
    textField: {
        contains: 'potato'
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any workaround to get such functionality for date/number type fields?

Comment: This question seems to be an almost identical copy of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72566024/2270233) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, using `LIKE` on non-text fields requires a cast of some kind. Prisma will not handle this for you, so you will need to use the [$queryRaw](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) method.

If you would like to see Prisma add this kind of functionality, you could open a [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this